# Applying heuristic methods for finding an Eulerian path

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am aware there are many algorithms to find Eulerian paths in undirected graphs; as far as I know they give a random (legitimate) path.

Given an Eulerian graph, I would like to find an Eulerian path that will pass through previously seen vertices as soon as possible; that is, while walking on the graph following that path, I'll visit previously visited vertices in my first steps. It can maybe be more formalized by saying that while walking on the graph the distribution of previously unvisited vertices is pretty much uniform on the path.

I am aware my request isn't very much formal (and I hope it is understood), therefore I understand it will be difficult to find a best solution, so I'm looking for heuristic methods to get better paths.

Comment: After visiting every vertex you could perform breadth first search starting from this vertex and add the distance from this vertex to each vertex's weight. When choosing next vertex for Eulerian path, just get a vertex with least weight.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: Thanks for the answer. The algorithms I know don't immediately choose the next vertex for the path; the one I am most familiar with chooses a neighbouring vertex and adds it to a stack. When I'm stuck (no neighbours), I add the current vertex to the Eulerian path, and use the top one in the stack as the next current vertex.

Comment: The algorithm you described looks like depth first search. I think it is not useful for Eulerian path.

Comment: I must have described it wrong then, sorry for that. Here it is: http://www.graph-magics.com/articles/euler.php

Comment: I've no idea why it may be needed to use stack to get Eulerian path. It may be easily done without the stack. As for question in OP, there is one more possibility: after producing some Eulerian path, you can swap or reverse its pieces between visiting some vertex, like this abcadea -> adeabca -> aedabca. Choose one swap or reverse operation, which makes your path "the best" and apply it, then repeat this procedure until you get no more improvements.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, thank you. The first idea seems more interesting because it looks like it can be applied to directed graphs too (in which I might be interested). Could you please refer me to the algorithm you are modifying there?

Comment: I didn't modify any algorithm there. I suggested to use [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). As for second approach, it can be applied to directed graphs if you use only swaps, not reverses.

Comment: I am familiar with BFS; do you suggest performing it v times (where v = number of vertices)? Then how do I find the Eulerian path? Choosing the minimal vertex each time won't necessarily give me such a path. Are you by chance talking about Hierholzer's algorithm?

Comment: That's right, I suggest performing it v times. And yes, Hierholzer's algorithm seems to be the right thing.

Comment: So you say choosing the minimal weight vertex, both in choosing the starting vertex (of any tour) as well as in choosing the next edge, will get me a better result? Could you please explain the reasoning behind it?

Comment: No, choosing the minimal weight vertex does not help in choosing the starting vertex (all weights are zero at that time). As for choosing the next edge, this heuristic gives somewhat better result (comparing to usual Eulerian path algorithms). Heuristic where you add logarithm of the distance and reset weight of visited vertexes to zero seems to be better. That's a greedy heuristic. It chooses locally optimal direction for the path (closer to visited nodes, which means more chances to revisit the same node sooner).

Comment: If you chose some formal definition for your task, you might try to find an optimal solution to it. Such optimization task looks similar to the Traveling Salesman Problem, so it most likely does not have a polynomial-time solution. You can try to use algorithms like [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or [Ant colony optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) to get a close to optimal result.